# Lambda Function in a Recursive Function in Python

Tags: python, function, lambda

I'm learning the following codes.

```
def merge(left, right, compare):

"""Assumes left and right are sorted lists and compare defines an ordering  on the elements.
Returns a new sorted (by compare) list containing the same elements as (left + right) would contain."""
    result = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if compare(left[i], right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    while (i < len(left)):
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while (j < len(right)):
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1
    return result



def mergeSort(L, compare = lambda x, y: x < y):
    """Assumes L is a list, compare defines an ordering on elements of L
   Returns a new sorted list with the same elements as L"""
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L)//2
        left = mergeSort(L[:middle], compare) # line A           
        right = mergeSort(L[middle:], compare) # line B
        return merge(left, right, compare)
```

The book asked me to give an example L = [2,1,4,5,3]

Then type mergeSort(L) in the console turns out to be [1,2,3,4,5]

My questions lie in the middle of mergeSort.

- Why "left" and "right" should return a sorted list (from the definition of function merge) after the above steps. Can anyone explain in details for what have happened when # line A & # line B are executed?
- I substitute:
  "left = mergeSort(L[:middle], compare)"  into  "left = mergeSort(L[:2], compare)".
  However, whenever I run mergeSort(L), Python always tells me 'Kernel died, restarting' after this substitution. Why the output is so different in this case when middle == 2? What's wrong when I substitute 'middle' into an integer?

NOTE: all of the above codes are from Figure 10.5 of the book *Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python*

Comment: I don't understand your first question. Second question: if you hardcode `middle` to `2` then the recursion base case will never trigger and the function will run forever.

Comment: How is "left and right" related to "the lambda"?

Comment: `Why "left" and "right" should return a sorted function`. left and right are list variables, they don't return a sorted function. The lambda function is needed for comparison. In other words: it defines how (in which order) you sort elements. Can you be more clear on what you are asking? I really struggle to understand what the questions are.

Comment: BTW, probably this will help to understand how quick sort works http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort/ P.S. if you substitute `middle` with concrete value not only function will never exit, that's simply incorrect since that's not a middle anymore.

Comment: @Nemoden, thank you. I've tried to edited the question in a different way and correct the mistake in the post.
I will take the link you provided as a reference~